# setcookie not working on my laptop browsers but working on Android, Java phones

Tags: php, android, browser

`setcookie` works well on Androids, Java phone but it not work on laptop browsers.

I am storing about 5 cookies, but only the login cookie is saving on laptop browsers.

What can I do for that?

Below shows my code.

```
setcookie(COOKIE_NAME, $cookie_value, time()+1800, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('dab_school_term', $term, $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('resume_hour',     $h,    $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('resume_minute',   $m,    $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('resume_period',   $am,   $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('close_hour',      $ch,   $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('close_minute',    $cm,   $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
setcookie('close_period',    $cam,  $exCookie, COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```

Comment: Impossible to answer with the code posted so far. Is `COOKIE_NAME` your login cookie? What is the value of `$exCookie`?

Comment: am sorry please... COOKIE_NAME( wich is logger )is a defined variable .. while exCookie is time()+(3600*24*30); thanks